# What's wrong with default posts archive?

Tags: archives

This is my template for archive.php template:

```
    <?php /* Template Name: Archives */ ?>
<?php include 'head.php' ?>

<body>
    <?php include 'header-page.php' ?>
    <main class="main_index">
        <section class="posts">
            <div class="center">
                <div>
                    <h2>
                        <?php single_cat_title(); ?>
                    </h2>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <h3>
                                <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </h3>
                        </a>
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                            <div class="post_thumbnail">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'post_cover' ); ?>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div>
                            <span><?php echo get_the_date(); ?></span>
                            <span><?php echo the_category(', '); ?></span>
                            <span>
                            <?php
echo get_the_tag_list('<p>',', ','</p>');
?>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile ?>
                    <nav class="pagination">
                        <?php
echo paginate_links( array(
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'          => __(' « '),
    'next_text'          => __(' » '),
) );
    ?>
                    </nav>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <p>Nic tu nie ma:(</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

It's works for ech category, tag and custom posts taxonomies and for custom posts archive, but not for default posts archive. When I want add "all posts" to my menu, I do not have "all" option like in my CPT. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'All Posts' archive is a Blog. You choose a Blog page in *Settings > Reading > Front page displays*. It can either be the front page or another page. The template that page uses depends on what templates your theme has and the [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/). home.php or index.php will likely be the template you use.